# Swift: Initializer memory issue

Tags: ios, swift

I'm a newbie for swift, Just a basic question:

```
let test: UITableView?

let test = UITableView()
```

what is the difference between these two tableviews. is there any memory issue with one of this or any drawbacks?

Comment: Also, just to let you know, Swift uses **ARC (Automatic Reference Counting)** for allocating and freeing-up memory, so you don't need to worry about memory issues when doing basic things (until you get to advanced reference cycles). See: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what is the difference between these two tableviews

```
let test: UITableView?

let test = UITableView()
```

The first line is a *declaration*, in which you're telling the compiler that `test` is an optional reference to a table view.

The second line combines a declaration and an assignment. The `UITableView()` part is the initializer that actually creates a table view object. That object is then assigned to `test`. Note that in this case you haven't explicitly specified the type, so the compiler infers it from the type of the thing that you're assigning, so the type of `test` here will be `UITableView` instead of `UITableView?`, which is to say the it won't be an optional. If you want, you can specify the type *and* assign a value all in one step, like this:

```
var test : UITableView? = UITableView()
```

I used `var` here because the fact that `test` is being declared as an optional means that its value might change later to nil.

Answer (score 3):

The first isn't a table view. It's a reference to a table view, with no value (`nil`). No table view was actually made.

This is a very basic/general question. You would have much faster/easier learning progress if you just read [the Swift Programming Language Guide](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html).

Answer (score 1):

A variable or constant followed by `: TYPE` means that it creates a memory location suitable for storing a reference of that type. This is a **declaration**.

```
let test: UITableView?
```

Using `= REFERENCE()` is an **assignment**, where you create a memory location to hold the reference to the **object**.

```
let test = UITableView()
```

This type is implicitly inferred, however you can still explicitly create the type by combining the two:

```
let test: UITableView = UITableView()
```

See **[The Basics](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html#ID310)** in the Swift documentation.

*Correct me if some of this information is incorrect or inaccurate*